# server selected unsupported version 301

Tags: logstash-forwarder

I have installed lOgstash,ELK and KIbana and all 3 working fine.
below is my logstash.conf

```
                input { 
            lumberjack {
                port => "5000"
                type => "common-logging-access"
                ssl_certificate => "C:/Sunil/HSL/SSL/logstash-forwarder.crt"
                ssl_key => "/Myfolder/SSL/logstash-forwarder.key" 
            }
            }

            filter {
              mutate {
                add_field => [ "hostip", "%{host}" ]
                add_field => ["systemName","common-logging-app"]
              }
              dns {
                reverse => [ "host" ]
                action => replace
             }
            }

            output {
              elasticsearch {
                host => "localhost"
                protocol => "http"
              }
            }

      and below is logstash-forwarder.conf.

                    {
              "network": {
                "servers": [ "127.0.0.1:5000" ],
                "ssl certificate": "/Myfolder/SSL/logstash-forwarder.crt"
               },
              "files": [
                {
                  "paths": [ 
                    "/var/logs/common-logging/*.log"
                  ],
                  "fields": { "type": "commonUiLogs" }
                }, {
         "paths": [ "/var/logs/Logstash/elasticsearch-1.3.4/logs/*.log"],
                  "fields": { "type": "apache" }
                }
              ]
            }
```

certificate is created using 
openssl req -x509 -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout logstash-forwarder.key -out logstash-forwarder.crt -days 365

When I run forwarder using command logstash-forwarder -config logstash-forwarder.conf

it shows error

2015/01/12 16:38:03.509240 Connecting to [127.0.0.1]:5000 (127.0.0.1)
2015/01/12 16:38:03.511240 Failed to tls handshake with 127.0.0.1 tls: server selected unsupported protocol version 301

I am using below versions
 logstash-1.4.2
 elasticsearch-1.3.4
 kibana-3.1.1
 I am using WIndows 7 64 bit machine.

Please help me on this.

regards,
Sunil.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash server is now offering tls protocol version which is now noticed to be unsecure. Please upadete java which runs the logstash instance to latest version.

Comment: Did you get it working with update or is there still something else?